# How to set each view own position in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Trying to make with RecyclerView something like this: [image]

There are a lot of views in recyclerView, and each view has it's own position parameters. For example, View1's position only in one row, view2's and view3's position one after another (like in linearLayout). Etc...
I think that realization is related with LayoutManager (maybe gridLayout). But how to set various position of each view?

Comment: hy please check this link. try recyclerview using horizontal recyclerview. http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use recyclerView, you should define several rows/items for the recycler view, means define different layouts and inflate + fill them with content by runtime.
In your case you should define three layouts.
1) A layout with one view
2) A layout with two views
3) A layout with three views
Now implement the **BaseAdapter** class to fill the recycler view with the view rows (the layouts you have defined)
For further information look at this [sample](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) from the developpers, how to use one layout.
The procedure for multiple layout rows (in your case 3) is almost the same